# Infinite Timedelta in Python

Tags: python, infinite, timedelta

How can you express an infinite timedelta in Python?

Up to now we use `datetime` from stdlib, but we could switch, if it is only supported in a third party library.

PostgreSQL does support it. And it would be handy in my case. I want to use it to express an not finished interval.

I could use `None`, but an infinite timedelta could avoid a lot of conditions (`if` statements).

Comment: An infinite timedelta? O_o so the result of `datetime.now() + infinite_timedelta` should be...what? `infinitely_in_the_future`?

Comment: Infinite time seems pretty undefined, so perhaps use `None`.

Comment: Maybe we should take a step back, what are you trying to accomplish with an infinite timedelta?

Comment: Why do you need it anyway? All the information present so far shows little practical use for such a thing. You'd probably be better off with something different.

Comment: @IntrepidBrit I updated the question: I want to use it to express an not finished interval.

Comment: Then surely as @Evert suggests, using `None` would do the trick instead..

Comment: Or just use the maximum representable value for timedelta or something that's sufficiently large - if you're allergic to if statements

Comment: Simple way - use `datetime` stating the timedelta's start if you do not have it's end yet. The *right* way would probably be to use a class with two datetime objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#infinite-dates-handling

> PostgreSQL can store the representation of an “infinite” date,
>   timestamp, or interval. Infinite dates are not available to Python, so
>   these objects are mapped to date.max, datetime.max, interval.max.
>   Unfortunately the mapping cannot be bidirectional so these dates will
>   be stored back into the database with their values, such as
>   9999-12-31.

Short answer: not supported.

Comment: I opened a feature request for support of infinity in psycopg2: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/283

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to express an unfinished interval is to use a datetime type's maximum value or `NULL` for the ending time.

As it was shown, you cannot really perform calculations involving the infinite value and get meaningful results.

Thus, `NULL` is better in this regard by simply not allowing you to.

Answer (score 1):

An "unfinished interval" can be expressed with [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) (and possibly subclass it to contain a flag stating `start` or `end`) - that's what I would do for a quick implementation.

When you have the interval's corresponding end or start), get the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) using their difference:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# represent infinite time from 1/1/2014 onwards
>>> start = datetime(2014, 1, 1)
# stop that time
>>> end = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
>>> interval = end - start
>>> interval
datetime.timedelta(365)
```

If you have the time to do this "the right way" you can  create a  speacialized `timedelta`-like class with two `datetime` objects (start and end). If one of them is missing you can assume it's an infinite timedelta and treat it as such.

Example:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
class SpecialTimedelta(object):

    def __init__(self, start=None, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

        if start and not isinstance(start, datetime):
            raise TypeError("start has to be of type datetime.datetime")
        if end and not isinstance(start, datetime):
            raise TypeError("end has to be of type datetime.datetime")

    def timedelta(self):
        if not (self.start and self.end):
            # possibly split cases
            return "infinite"
            # alternatives:
            # return self.start or self.end
            # raise OverflowError("Cannot quantiate infinite time with timedelta")
        return self.end - self.start

print SpecialTimedelta(datetime(1986, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 1, 1)).timedelta()
# out: 10592 days, 0:00:00
print SpecialTimedelta(datetime(1986, 1, 1)).timedelta()
# out: infinite
```